(Resolved) WhatsApp Flows V5.0 (RadiobuttonsGroup with images)
I'm building a WELJ with Meta documentation, but when I use one of its example, the API show me errors, even though I just copy and paste the WELJ. The error message is:
"validation_errors": [ { "error": "INVALID_FLOW_JSON_VERSION", "error_type": "FLOW_JSON_ERROR", "message": "The property \"alt-text\" cannot be specified at \"$root/screens/0/layout/children/0/data-source/0\".", "line_start": 1, "line_end": 1, "column_start": 428, "column_end": 437 } ]
I don't know why this error is showed, because I just copy and paste the WELJ in documentation. And the Changelog recommend us to use the version 5.0.
I've tried to use the example in Meta Documentation and see how it works on WhatsApp. I hope someone help me with this topic.
SOLUTION: I opened a ticket at Meta and the problem was with the API, as the documentation was accepting the component, but the API did not. Now it's working

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can you please share a minimal Flow JSON to reproduce this issue?
It seems from the message that you have an invalid property "alt-text" as it says: The property "alt-text" cannot be specified at ...

Sorry, I should have updated this question. I opened a ticket at Meta and the problem was with the API, as the documentation was accepting the component, but the API did not
